# Tomcat - Session ID changes for every request through vritual host

Tags: apache, tomcat

For example, all normal requests go through `virtual host 443` and to tomcat with the same JSESSIONID. But somewhere in the process the APP needs to send traffic through  `virtual host 1234` for some other app functionally to work and that's when JSESIONID changes and then eventually 443 and 1234 both keeps flipping JSESSIONID....

The issue happens only in Docker container when the setup is like this  `Httpd pod forwards requests to -> Tomcat pod`

In production, we have a single server for `apache and tomcat` and it retains session.

Is there a way I can preserve JESSIONID between both virtual hosts connection?

```
443 traffic holds a different JSESSION ID
1234 traffic holds a different JESSION ID
```

There is no loadbalancer for tomcat since its just a single server. And I'm using mod_jk. I've set sticky_session=true for AJP worker.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
       ServerName .. 
       SSL certs..
       JkMount /app/*
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:1234>
       ServerName .. 
       SSL certs..
       JkMount /app-service/*
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How many `httpd`s do you have? How many Tomcats?

Comment: Two httpd servers and Two Tomcat for testing

Comment: Can you confirm that your Tomcat `JSESSIONID` cookies look like `abc123.nodeName`?